# Use Material UI theme attributes for styling highcharts - React

Tags: highcharts, material-ui, react-highcharts

I have been using Material ui themes for styled components in React. Now, We have a requirement in our application to use highcharts. But I still wanted to retain the same themeing for highcharts as well. Is there a way we could integrate Material UI theme to style highcharts chart? I did google this a lot before finally deciding to raise the question here. I know that highcharts provide their own theme. But I do not want to make the code messier with multiple themes. Is there a way to achieve this in a cleaner way? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts have a possibility to set themes by Highcharts.setOptions to create schemate fit to you. That you can see there are specific sets for charts elements for that material UI it's not changing charts looks.
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes#creating-your-own-theme

```
// set the theme
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                [1, 'rgb(240, 240, 255)']
            ]
        },
        borderWidth: 2,
        plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)',
        plotShadow: true,
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },
    title: {
        style: {
            color: '#000',
            font: 'bold 16px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    },
    subtitle: {
        style: {
            color: '#666666',
            font: 'bold 12px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: '#000',
        tickColor: '#000',
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#000',
                font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
        title: {
            style: {
                color: '#333',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'

            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        alternateGridColor: null,
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        lineColor: '#000',
        lineWidth: 1,
        tickWidth: 1,
        tickColor: '#000',
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#000',
                font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
        title: {
            style: {
                color: '#333',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        itemStyle: {
            font: '9pt Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif',
            color: 'black'

        },
        itemHoverStyle: {
            color: '#039'
        },
        itemHiddenStyle: {
            color: 'gray'
        }
    },
    credits: {
        style: {
            right: '10px'
        }
    },
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: '#99b'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw that we can create our own theme. But I want to reuse material ui theme and apply it on highcharts. Is it possible?

Comment: No it's not working, Materia UI don't override Highcharts styles.